# How to force help to use overridden __doc__

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

Let's assume I define a simple class `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):
    """This is Foo"""
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.__doc__ = "This is {} Foo".format(label)

    def __call(self, *args):
        ... # Some behavior which depends on the constructor arguments.
```

I see that object `__doc__` is picked up by `?` in IPython:

```
In [1]: %doctest_mode
Exception reporting mode: Plain
Doctest mode is: ON
>>> some = Foo("some")
>>> ?some
Type:            Foo
String form:     <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f01620a49b0>
Docstring:       This is some Foo
Class docstring: This is Foo
```

but ignored by `help`:

```
>>> help(some)

Help on Foo in module __main__ object:

class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  This is Foo
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, label)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
(END)
```

Is it possible to influence `help` behavior without modifying `Class docstring`? I would like to  `Class docstring` to be ignored when working with instances.

Comment: I don't see your point. First of all, it's strange for an instance to have a class at all. Secondly: even in that case the information in the instance docstring should be different (and not overlapping) with that of the class docstring... the class docstring should *always* be useful. AFAIK it's not possible to "specialize" the docstring in an instance, and, as I said, I believe it's the right thing to do. Sure: you can provide your own help function/hack into ipython to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Bakuriu The context is as follows. `Foo` is a callable object and its behavior depends on the arguments which are passed to constructor.  So behavior of an object is much more important than behavior of the class. My intuition was along the lines you describe but I thought I'll ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I wouldn't recommend it! If you seriously change the logic depending on the arguments, you are probably better of using a factory function and several distinct (sub-)classes.

After having said that: it's possible. One way would be using dynamic types and subclassing. However you need to use `__new__` instead of `__init__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    """This is Foo"""
    def __new__(cls, label):
        newcls = type('FooSubclass', (Foo, ), {'__doc__': "This is {} Foo".format(label)})
        return newcls

>>> help(Foo('a'))
Help on class FooSubclass in module __main__:

class FooSubclass(Foo)
 |  This is a Foo
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      FooSubclass
 |      Foo
 |      __builtin__.object
 |  
 |  Static methods inherited from Foo:
 |  
 |  __new__(cls, label)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Foo:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Comment: Haven't thought about it. Thanks. Will work just fine. Sadly I have no control over overall structure so more intuitive design is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing the `help` function requires changes to its implementation from what I've understood. It is much easier to create a little helper function that temporarily re-assigns `__doc__` on the class:

```
def my_help(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, type):  # instances
        old_doc, type(obj).__doc__ = type(obj).__doc__, obj.__doc__
        help(type(obj))
        type(obj).__doc__ = old_doc
    else:
        help(obj)
```

This yields the, from what I've understood, wanted effect of having the docstring of the instance replace that of the class:

```
my_help(Foo('foo'))
Help on class Foo in module __main__:

class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  This is foo Foo
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, label)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 #  .. snipped ..
```

I don't really like this, though, and also know that you must perform a `try-except` in there for classes that don't allow you to set attributes on them like that. In short, doable but clunky.